# Can't create an AbstractRoutingDataSource that needs some data from another database

Tags: spring, datasource

We currently have an application which uses multiple databases with the same schema. At the moment we're using a custom solution for switching between them based on the user's session. This works via

```
public final class DataSourceProxy extends BasicDataSource {

    ...

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && auth.getDetails() instanceof Map) {

        Map<String, String> details = (Map<String, String>) auth.getDetails();
        String targetUrl = details.get("database");

        Connection c = super.getConnection();
        Statement  s = c.createStatement();
        s.execute("USE " + targetUrl + ";");
        s.close();
        return c;
    } else {
        return super.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Now we want to build a solution using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. The problem is:

```
@Component
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Autowired
    DbDetailsRepositoy repo;

    public CustomRoutingDataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        for(DBDetails dbd : repo.findAll() {
            // create DataSource and put it into the map
        }
        setTargetDataSources(new HashMap<Object, Object>());
    }   

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null && auth.getDetails() instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, String> details = (Map<String, String>) auth.getDetails();
            return details.get("database");
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Inside the constructor (or even via `@PostConstruct`) we have to fill the `targetDataSources Map`. But(!) for this we need the connection details which are stored in another database, which has its own DataSource and Entity Manager.

It seems like Spring can't determine the order of Bean construction, or maybe I'm just missing something. It always gives a `NullPointerException` when accessing the repository (which btw is a `JpaRepository`).

We're using Spring 3.2.3, Spring Data, Hibernate 4.2. Complete Annotation and Java-Code configuration of Spring and Spring Security.

Please help us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring of course has to call the constructor *before* it can populate the properties. But that's not a Spring thing, that's basic Java 101 and one of the plenty downsides of using field injection.

To avoid this, simply add your dependencies to the constructor:

```
@Component
class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

  @Autowired
  public CustomRoutingDataSource(DbDetailsRepository repo, Environment environment) {
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: yeah sure... sometimes one can't see the most obvious things