# AbstractRoutingDataSource change map in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have now 2 tables in database:

1. User
2. user_database

In user I store login, password,role

In user_database i store database driver,url,password and user.
Diagram database
[image]

I want user login to my page and next connection what he done will be sent to user database. Why i need what? I planing map popular e commerce and create android application where user login and see store data, can add and view product orders. 

Now time to go practice, my knowledge in spring technology is small please explain me something when I doing wrong.
All examples on web for `AbstractRoutingDataSource` have declaration datasource in persistence file or create datasource bean and start using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.
In my project I don't now user connection and i need get this from database. I was try get using repository and this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575648/3037869
but i getting null on `@Autowired` in controller, i think connection for repository is null. How to set connection for this repository and set Route? Defect this method is when i add user i need restart server to refresh connection. 

Next try what i using now is class `User` implement `UserDetails` after user login i can get user connection from `getPrincipal()` and add to map.

```
private void setDataSources() {
    HashMap<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    targetDataSources.put("auth", dataSourceBuilder.build());
    setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceBuilder.build());
    if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()!=null) {
        User user=(User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(user.getUserDatabase().getDriver());
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(user.getUserDatabase().getDriver());
        dataSourceBuilder.url(user.getUserDatabase().getUrl());
        dataSourceBuilder.username("3450_Menadzer");
        dataSourceBuilder.password(user.getUserDatabase().getPassword());
        targetDataSources.put("user", dataSourceBuilder.build());
    }
    setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    afterPropertiesSet(); //map is refresh when i add this

}
```

I run this method on constuctor and determineCurrentLookupKey

```
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()!=null) {
            setDataSources();

            return "user";
        }

        return "auth";
}
```

This is working but when i refresh 3-4 times request for user database i getting

```
User 3450_Menadzer already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

Setting connection map manualy and not refreshing every method `determineCurrentLookupKey` run i don't have this problem. I think my method is not clossing connection. How i can clean this? This is possible to better method to route connection?

**EDIT**
@SergeBallesta i change some code from your examples
This is my class for map

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class DataSourceMap {
    private Map<Object,Object> dataSourceMap;
    public DataSourceMap()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        dataSourceMap=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        dataSourceMap.put("auth",dataSourceBuilder.build());
    }
    public void addDataSource(String session,DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSourceMap.put(session,dataSource);
    }
    public Map<Object,Object> getDataSourceMap()
    {
        return dataSourceMap;
    }
    public void removeSource(String session)
    {
        dataSourceMap.remove(session);
    }
}
```

For `AbstractRoutingDataSource` i done some changes, i was add         `afterPropertiesSet()` beacuse datasource not refresh. I done some refresh and i not getting error i think this is working. I need test this for more databases in future

```
@Component
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource{
    @Autowired
    DataSourceMap dataSources;
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        setDataSources(dataSources);
        afterPropertiesSet();
        System.out.println("test");
        if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()!=null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)
                    RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            return request.getSession().getId();
        }

        return "auth";
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSources(DataSourceMap dataSources) {
        System.out.println("data adding");
        setTargetDataSources(dataSources.getDataSourceMap());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? I have the same mission after user login, connect to a base db and get data source then CRUD to taht data source! But I am very new in Spring Framework, I tried a month but no good result. I hope your code can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, per user database is a very uncommon design. If all those databases will end with same structure, please do not do that in a real world application, but just add user_id in your tables and queries.

Next, I found another (not full) example of a dynamic AbstractRoutingDataSource in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177079/3545273) of mine.

And one big difference between my code (beware never tested) and your question is that I use a SessionListener to close the databases to avoid that the number of open database grows indefinitively.

If you to this to learn Spring, you could try the following pattern (bottom-up description) :

- a session scoped bean that would hold the actual database connection for a user, the connection should be created on first request (to be sure that user id is present in session) and cached for subsequent uses. A destroy method (automaticaly called by Spring when session is closed) should close the connection.
- an `AbstractRoutingDataSource`, that would be injected with a proxy to above holder, and that would ask actual datasource to the holder

As in the other answer, if same user is likely to have many simultaneous sessions, you could have a singleton been injected in session holders that would keep the actual database connections along with the number of active sessions. That way you would get one single connection per user, no matter how many concurrent sessions he could have.

Comment: i was looked your old example, i think this is possible to do but you need me explain something. `sessionDestroyed` method is in class what implement `HttpSessionListener` ? Where you exectue `AbstractRoutingDataSource` this is compoment? Adding connection database is in servlet context or class?

Comment: @seti : I have slightly modified my old example. The idea is that the map userId -> dataSource is a singleton bean injected in the AbstractRoutingDataSource implementation, in the HttpSessionListener that will close the datasources and removes them from the map. And you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/182203/3545273) an example of a listener for the successful login event, that could store the database in the map

Comment: i edit my question your logic helped me. Can you explain what is diffirent in my old code and new (this is working). In Old code i was create dataSource map set and refresh, in new i getting datasource from `@Autowired` class set and refresh.